# Xcode 5, custom UITableViewCell class for Dynamic Prototype

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm using Xcode 5, and want to be using the recommended best practices from Apple, which includes dynamic prototype cells and using `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier`.

I have created a storyboard and dropped a `UITableView` with 1 prototype dynamic cell on it. I've set the class of the cell to `ItemCell`, and set the reuse identifier to `ItemCell`.

The ItemCell class contains a `nameLabel` IBOutlet, which I've connected to the label within the prototype cell by dragging.

In the ViewController, I register the `ItemCell` class to be used for the `ItemCell` reuse identifier:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_tableView registerClass:[ItemCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
}
```

In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, I dequeue the cell and set the properties for the nameLabel. self.items is an NSArray of strings.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
}
```

So: it's being created as an ItemCell, but it's not loading it from the storyboard. I've confirmed this by overriding initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier and initWithCoder, to see which was being called:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"NOT STORYBOARD");
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"Yay, it's working!");
    }
    return self;

}
```

Every time, it's `initWithStyle` that's being called. From everything I've read, this should be working. I can't find anything that indicates I need to somehow register the class differently when it's in a storyboard, but clearly the cell isn't aware that it's got a storyboard associated with it.

I'm sure I'm making a total newbie mistake, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to (and should not) call `registerClass` for prototype cells defined in the storyboard. `initWithCoder` is called automatically if a prototype cell has to
be instantiated from the storyboard.